# Is it expected that VM VirtualBox cannot manage more than 16 cores?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have configured a 32 core (dual Intel Xeon Processor E5-2698 v3) with 128GB RAM, running CentOS 7 as the host OS.

When running VM VirtualBox with a Windows 7 Professional client, specifying any more than 16 cores leads to a very slow boot (20 cores), failure to boot (more than 24), or the system locking up after boot (20).

The client is relatively stable on 16 cores however.

What is the origin of this limitation? Note the system is running with hyperthreading, exposing 64 cores to the host OS.

Comment: [Virtual Box Documentation 3.5.2. Processor Tab](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-processor)

Comment: "You should not configure virtual machines to use more CPU cores than are available physically. This includes real cores, with no hyperthreads." I believe this is what you are referring to. I have 32 real cores however discuss problems running significantly less.

Comment: Wild guess: No-one's ever tested it to 32 cores ;) I've only 12 real cores [24 with HT] & can confirm performance is optimal on a single VM by assigning all 12, which leaves the rest of my machine happily working "in the HT" of each core & lets the VM get on with intensive tasks without swamping my other work.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 Home or Pro?
Home only supports 1 CPU socket, Pro allows for 2.
32-bit versions of Win7 can utilize 32 (real, not hyper-threading cores), 64-bit does 256.

So I'm guessing you use Home, but above 16 they come from both CPU's which causes the instability.

Comment: Windows 7 Professional, I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

First a remark: You do not have a 32-core computer, but a 16-core one with
[Hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).
These threads are light-weight semi-cores that do not have the same power
as a real core.
In Intel documentation, Hyper-threading is said to improve performance by at most
30%, as some CPU parts are unique and common to its two hyper-threads,
so cause waiting.

Second, a remark about the virtual vCPU of VirtualBox: They are not real cores,
nor are they using real cores. They are only threads started by the host emulator,
each behaving somewhat like a core for the VM.

So what you really have for a 20-cores VM is one host process, VirtualBox,
with 20 threads. The VM itself is an operating system, with perhaps hundreds
of active processes that operate the OS and its emulated hardware, all using the
vCPUs that it thinks are real cores.

With that many active threads, thread-switching starts to be an important factor,
thus slowing down the host operating system. Performance then depends on the
efficiency of the scheduling algorithms of the host and how well they handle
that number of active threads.

For performance, the best advice I can give is perhaps a bit draconian:

- Turn off Hyper-threading in the BIOS (if possible), so cores are real
  physical and not virtual semi-fictions
- Do not allocate more than that number of cores to the VM.
  Excedding it only means that some vCPUs will be idle at any given moment,
  and that context-switching will become a larger factor.
- Update to Windows 10, which has a better scheduling algorithm.

Comment: To be clear, I have two 16 core processors, two Intel Xeon Processor E5-2698 v3 units with 16 real cores each.

Comment: Understood, a nice setup. That doesn't change the basics in the above text.

Comment: I have added a third advice: Update to Windows 10.

Comment: That's not how VirtualBox works. The virtual cores are not regular application threads, they are proper hardware-virtualised core allocations. You appear to be describing an emulator.

Comment: They've got two [E5-2698 v3](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/81060/intel-xeon-processor-e5-2698-v3-40m-cache-2-30-ghz.html), which is 32 real cores (64 with HT).

Comment: @OrangeDog: You are wrong. VirtualBox cannot take over a core. Otherwise you cannot use it to allocate more cores than in the computer, which people do.

Comment: @harrymc that doesn’t follow

Comment: @OrangeDog: So what follows?